# How to sum up columns by a foreign key that's in two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Currently I'm achieving the result below using a table called `league_standing` and updating it after every match. I'd like to be able to do with one query against the table `matches`.

[image]

`Teams` play each other twice, both home and away. Notice how `team_id` is in the two columns `home_team_id` and `away_team_id`

```
+----------------------------------+
|              Matches             |
+----------------------------------+
| id                               |
| league_id (FK League)            |   
| season_id (FK Season)            |
| home_team_id (FK Team)           |
| away_team_id (FK Team)           | 
| home_score                       |
| away_score                       |
| confirmed                        |
+----------------------------------+
```

Here is what I have tried but failed:

```
select team.name, HomePoints + AwayPoints points
from team join (
    select team.id, 
        sum(case when home.home_score > home.away_score then 3
            when home.home_score = home.away_score then 1 else 0 end) HomePoints,
        sum(case when away.away_score > away.home_score then 3 else 0 end) AwayPoints
    from team 
    join matches home on team.id = home.home_team_id
    join matches away on team.id = away.away_team_id
    WHERE home.league_id = 94
        AND home.season_id = 82
        AND home.confirmed IS NOT NULL 
    group by id
) temp on team.id = temp.id
order by points desc;
```

It's giving me the wrong points:

[image]

and this one gives me the correct result of league_standings of home team only

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT team.name, home_team_id AS team_id,
        COUNT(*) AS played,
        SUM((CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS won,
        SUM((CASE WHEN away_score > home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS lost,
        SUM((CASE WHEN home_score = away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS drawn,
        SUM(home_score) AS goalsFor,
        SUM(away_score) AS goalsAgainst,
        SUM(home_score - away_score) AS goalDifference,
        SUM((CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 3 WHEN home_score = away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS points
    FROM matches
    INNER JOIN team ON matches.home_team_id = team.id
    WHERE league_id = 94
        AND season_id = 82
        AND confirmed IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY home_team_id
UNION
    SELECT team.name, away_team_id AS team_id,
        COUNT(*) AS played,
        SUM((CASE WHEN away_score > home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS won,
        SUM((CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS lost,
        SUM((CASE WHEN home_score = away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as drawn,
        SUM(away_score) AS goalsFor,
        SUM(home_score) AS goalsAgainst,
        SUM(away_score - home_score) AS goalDifference,
        SUM((CASE WHEN away_score > home_score THEN 3 WHEN away_score = home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS points
    FROM matches
    INNER JOIN team ON matches.away_team_id = team.id
    WHERE league_id = 94
        AND season_id = 82
        AND confirmed IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY away_team_id
) x 
GROUP BY team_id
ORDER BY points DESC;
```

[image]

If it helps, my database schema:

[image]

I'm stuck! Hope you can help.

Comment: Don't do it.  One of the rules of database normalization is to not store calculated values.  You can always present the standings by running a select query on you other tables.

Comment: @DanBracuk So would it be better to run a select query on matches and then use PHP to calculate the standings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would compute the home and away results for each team, and then do the aggregation.
The following query should do what you need. You just need to join the results with the teams table in order to get the team name.
The syntax is working for PostgreSQL, may be you will need to change something for mysql.

```
select team_id, count(*) as P, sum(W) as W, sum(D) as D, sum(L) as L, sum(GF) as GF, sum(GA) as GA, sum(GD) as GD, sum(PTS) as PTS from (
select home_team_id as team_id,       
       case when home_score > away_score then 1
            else 0 end as W,
       case when home_score = away_score then 1
            else 0 end as D,
       case when home_score < away_score then 1
            else 0 end as L,
       home_score as GF,
       away_score as GA,
       home_score-away_score as GD,
       case when home_score > away_score then 3
            when home_score = away_score then 1 
            else 0 end as PTS            
from matches
where league_id = 94 and season_id = 82 and confirmed is not null
union all
select away_team_id as team_id,       
       case when home_score < away_score then 1
            else 0 end as W,
       case when home_score = away_score then 1
            else 0 end as D,
       case when home_score > away_score then 1
            else 0 end as L,
       away_score as GF,
       home_score as GA,
       away_score-home_score as GD,
       case when home_score < away_score then 3
            when home_score = away_score then 1 
            else 0 end as PTS            
from matches
where league_id = 94 and season_id = 82 and confirmed is not null
) as results
group by team_id
order by pts DESC,gd DESC,gf DESC;
```

By the way, I don't think that storing the results in a table and updating them after each match is a bad idea.
Recomputing always the same results is something that should be avoided, especially if there are many users that are interested in consulting the rank.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll stick with the LeagueStanding table but I want to implement a feature to show standings of Last x Games which would be dynamic across the season so will use this!

Comment: how do you add an order and limit to this query if Union doesn't allow it? Say I want to get standings based on the previous 5 games?

Comment: If you want to compute standing based on some games, you do not need the limit clause. You need to filter the matches with a specific condition in the where clause, for instance,
... where ... and confirmed is not null and (<date_of_the_match> between <initial_date> and <final_date>)
If you want to compute the last <n> games in the query itself, you need to insert an additional subquery in the where clause of both the subqueries.
I suggest not to do this, but to first compute the date interval of the matches in which you are interested and then to add a simple condition in the where clauses.